# "AttributeError: module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'set_alignment' "

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following error when importing PIL on python 3.5

> AttributeError: module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'set_alignment'

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Check whether you have the latest version of Pillow.

Comment: That was it! Thank a lot

Answer (score 3):

upgrade your pillow package by running

```
pip install --upgrade pillow
```